# Wordpress advanced querying for Woocommerce custom filtering

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, filtering

I want to make a Ajax Loader of products.

So let's say my product have id 18534.We start in `wp_term_relationships` and find 9 rows there with `object_id = 18534` and  `term_taxonomy_id`'s. We need only 1 of them (for 1 filtering, I want to start from 1 than try do more). So i found in `wp_term_taxonomy term_taxonomy_id = 171` (same like in wp_term_relationships row). In this row we have `term_id = 171` and `taxonomy = "pa_line"`.

Well but now I need a value right? We go to table `wp_terms` where I have a values of filtering. So I have row here `term_id 171` and name (value) I'm looking for which is Basic.

My question is: how the can I get products where `"pa_line" == Basic`?!

Comment: WooCommerce "attributes" are custom taxonomies. So to query all the products that have `pa_line` values of "Basic" you would use [WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) with taxonomy query parameters.

Comment: Yayks! Okay so another question: How to get products by price for example all lower than 100$?

Comment: That's a totally separate question (though i can tell you it is a query with meta parameters) and should be asked as a new question, and not as a comment to an old question.